# Redirect to html href url (li a tag) won't work, styling issue?

Tags: html, css

I have some weird issue. Inside my html I have the very same href url for both the  tags within the sidebar dropdown ('teams') and the 'about' tag in the bottom of my sidebar (for testing purposes).

When i click on 'about' it correctly redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/ .

But when i click on a team on the left, it just shows the correct url in a pop-up but neither redirects me nor changes the url in the browser.

Why is that?

[image]

About tag:

```
      <div class="about">
        <a href="/dashboard/">About</a>
```

Team tag:

```
          <ul class="subbar">
            <li><a class="team" href="/dashboard/" id="69">FC Bayern München</a></li>
```

whole HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% csrf_token %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "/styles.css" %}">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/dasocc_site/dasocc_app/static/images/dasoccfavicon.png"/>
  <title>DASOCC</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="outerContainer">

    <!-- Sidebar -->

    <div id="sidebar">
      <header>
        <a href="#">Dasocc</a>
      </header>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="countries"><img src="{% static "images/germany.png" %}" alt="germany">1. Bundesliga
          <ul class="subbar">
            <li><a class="team" href="/dashboard/" id="69">FC Bayern München</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Borussia Dortmund</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Bayer 04 Leverkusen</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">RB Leipzig</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">VfL Wolfsburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SC Freiburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Eintracht Frankfurt</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Borussia M. Gladbach</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">FC Schalke 04</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">TSG 1899 Hoffenheim</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">1. FC Union Berlin</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Fortuna Düsseldorf</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SV Werder Bremen</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">1. FC Köln</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">SC Paderborn</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">FC Augsburg</a></li>
            <li><a class="team">Hertha BSC Berlin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


      <div class="about">
        <a href="/dashboard/">About</a>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: rgb(30,75,150);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(30,75,150,1) 0%, rgba(36,81,157,1) 46%, rgba(51,90,156,1) 100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: table-cell;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#sidebar header {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#sidebar header a {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar header a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}

#sidebar .nav a {
  background: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

#sidebar .nav img {
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#sidebar .nav li {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar .nav a:hover {
  color: #D4C227;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

JS / AJAX:

```
$('ul.subbar li a').on('click', function(e) { // Start function when user clicks on a team in the navbar
// e.preventDefault(); // Stop loading new link
var team_id = $(this).attr("id"); // Assign id of clicked team name to variable 'team_id'
console.log(team_id); // test
$.ajax({    // initialize AJAX POST with the stated attributes
  method: "GET",
  url: "/dashboard/",
  data: {'team': team_id},
  data_type: "json",
  success: function(team) {

    }
  });
});
```

Another SO thread pointed to a wrongly set Z-index. I tried it by removing mine but that didn't change anything.

Comment: hey Paulie, you are probably a bot, but I inserted the code as required..

Comment: it's hard to tell from just these short snippets, it would be nice if you can post the whole HTML code.

Comment: Check your JavaScript for a line of code that looks like this `preventDefault()`. If found, this could be preventing the link from working

Comment: @KyleAlexander I had that included, indeed. But i removed it and it still won't load.

Comment: Why does only the first team have an href and an id? All the others are different.

Comment: @Kev for testing purposes.

Comment: Does the Javascript get executed? (i.e., does the team_id end up in the console?). That Javascript is the only thing that can really cause problems, as far as I can see.

Comment: Hmm I don't know the reason behind using ajax here, but it seems to me that it shouldn't be used if you're simply trying to redirect to a different page

Answer (score 1):

The reason the link  tag doesn't work is that in your JavaScript code, you are sending an AJAX request to the server, which I guess is not live at the moment, so it will not send any response.

This code should be working fine if you are testing on a live server, but statically, you should comment this JavaScript function to be able to continue designing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Javascript prevented it from loading. I had another preventDefault attribute within JS (whyever).

Thanks for your inputs.